# Moving highcharts export menu button to a different div

Tags: highcharts

Is is possible to move the highcharts hamburger menu into another div? I wanted to place this menu button in either a header or a footer to the displayed chart and not have it show in the chart area. I tried playing around with the css and set the :

```
navigation: {
      buttonOptions: {
          symbolX: 23,
          symbolY: -22
      }
}
```

so i can push the menu button to the area of the header but it seemed that the icon disappeared either behind the header div or just doesn't show once it leave the chart display area.

Anyone have any input on this matter?

Comment: Add fiddle to demonstrate the issue

Comment: Exporting menu button is part of a chart so you wont be able to move it outside the svg content (chart).

Comment: @morganfree bummer. But thanks for letting me know.